# The best way to clean up a SQL text field for output

Tags: postgresql, csv, text

I need to pull some data for a report. The field is a text field that is populated by users to keep track of their notes, and there is a lot of automatic formatting that happens on the CMS user end that makes it easier for the counselors to read. When I go to pull the data out of the PostgreSQL DB, however, I see all of the paragraph marks and text formatting instructions in the field. I'd like to know if there is a way to write something to clean up the data for the output so it can be more easily read on the back end if I want to pull it into a CSV with other information.

Here's an example of one of the text fields.

[Text Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90dlV.png)

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be HTML. Whatever client language you are using to access the data almost certainly has a HTML parser which can return the raw text.

Oh, and in future try and paste actual text rather than pictures. Even if your post isn't automatically closed, most people won't bother to read it and Clinton your picture.